# Do I need to enable TLS support for postfix?

Tags: configuration, postfix, smtp, tls, spam

I need to send out notifications from my web-app and I've setup postfix as a null client on my server. So in my `/etc/postfix/master.cf` I have commented out the lines

```
#smtp      inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
#local     unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
```

So after I did that when I try to use telnet, it blocks me out.

```
$ telnet localhost 25
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

And when I use sendmail I am able to send emails, which is what I want. So far so good.

Now, I'm concerned about spammers not using my SMTP server as an open relay. To this end, do I need to turn on TLS and SMTP Auth support in postfix or is just disabling network access to postfix (by commenting out those two lines in master.cf) sufficient?

In other words, in my current setup - with TLS turned OFF and network access to postfix disabled - is there a possibility of my SMTP server being compromised?

Comment: If you have _completely disabled_ access to SMTP, it _cannot be used_. TLS vs no TLS doesn't make any difference.

Comment: The line I commented out is smtp via network interfaces
`smtp      inet` . There is another line in the config file which goes like `smtp unix` which I'm guessing is the one that needs to be enabled to make `sendmail` work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TLS is used for secure communications with your server.  Most spammers and legitimate mailservers would rarely use TLS to send mail to/through your server.  It is more common that you would use TLS when sending mail from your email program, i.e. Outlook, Thunderbird, etc.

With network access disabled, you wouldn't be able to send mail from an email client, but, spammers and legitimate mail wouldn't be able to be delivered to your server.

Disabling smtp should work in your situation.

Comment: "legitimate mail wouldn't be able to be delivered to your server." 

Yeah, I'm using this postfix server to just SEND email.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest setting up Postfix with TLS & SMTP Authentication.

[This link](http://adomas.org/2006/08/postfix-dovecot/) should explain most of the process on properly securing your mailserver.